# Raspberry Pi only showing solid green light

Tags: boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B 4GB RAM model and it was working fine until one day when I powered it up it started showing only a solid green light. I removed the SD card then powered it up and I got the same. I tried the same SD card with 2 different Raspberry Pi's and both booted fine, did the same with the PSU that came with the Pi.  I also started noticing that the green light is only switched on for around a minute or so and then it switches off completely (with the `psu` connected) . Is it safe to assume that the Pi board is dead?

Comment: Have you checked the boot problem sticky at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=437084#p1485558 - note esp the SD card comment re 32Gb and any flashing lights you get.

Comment: @Andrew i did check it out! Unfortunately nothing in that thread mentions a solid green light so I'm just confused right now. There are absolutely no flashing lights with or without the SD card and the light switches off on its own after sometime